# How to use :nth-child for alternate rows

Tags: html, css

I want to style my accordion with border-top and border-bottom for even number of rows Ex: 2, 4 ,6 etc.
I tried with `:nth-child` but it is not reflecting my parent `div` but it is reflecting my child element.

## code

```
<div className="accordion" id="adsdfsdf">
  <div className="accordionitem">
     <div className="accordion-card">
        <div className="accordion-card-header" id="aada">
           <h3 className="mb-0 w-100">
             <a
               className="collapsed"
                  role="button"
                   >
             <span className="icon-left">
               <i className=" a-minus" />
                 <i className="a-plus" />
              </span>

             </a>
           </h3>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
<div className="accordion" id="adsdfsdf">
  <div className="accordionitem">
     <div className="accordion-card">
        <div className="accordion-card-header" id="aada">
           <h3 className="mb-0 w-100">
             <a
               className="collapsed"
                  role="button"
                   >
             <span className="icon-left">
               <i className=" a-minus" />
                 <i className="a-plus" />
              </span>

             </a>
           </h3>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

## css

```
.accordion-card-header {
boder-top: 1px solid red;
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Please add the related CSS in question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. you need to use `:nth-child(even)` to style even rows and `:nth-child(odd)` to style odd rows. For the further reference you can go through [nth-child() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Here is a small demo

```css
div:nth-child(odd) {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div>odd</div>
<div>even</div>
<div>odd</div>
<div>even</div>
```